# How to use function which() in R on values with Serbian latin letters?

Tags: r, encoding

I have a variable **x** whose values contain Serbian latin letters (*č,ć,ž,š,đ*) and I need to extract indices of the rows that contain a specific value. When I use the function *which(data$x == "value that **does NOT** contain Serbian latin letter")*, I get the result, but when I use *which(data$x == "value that **DO** contain Serbian latin letter")*, the result I get is **integer(0)**.

I would appreciate if someone could give me any hint.

### UPDATE:

Let's say I have data frame **data** and the variable **x** which has values  "žaba", "ptica","žaba", "žaba", "ptica".

I want to get indices of elements with value **"žaba"** which would be 1,3 and 4.
I tried it using function **which(data$x == "žaba")**.

It works when I create data within the R console but it does not work when I import data from Excel.

### UPDATE 2:

Besides the issue with Serbian letters, there is an issue with a hyphen. When I substitute Serbian letters with their corresponding Latin letters and when I remove hyphens, then I don't have any issue with the formula.

Anyways, if there is a way to overcome this without data modifications, I would prefer that way.

Comment: Please give us a small example of your data and the exact comparison that you are trying.  It would be fine to have just two strings - one with and one without the  Serbian characters.

Comment: @G5W I added an update. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: There is quite a lot that you have not specified. When you read the strings from Excel into R, do they display properly in R?  Are you reading from an xlsx file or a csv file? What code do you use to read in the data? (If you use a package, please specify that.) It probably would be helpful for you to type `sessionInfo()` and show us the output in the locale section.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know the answer depends on so many info. Here there are:
All the data are displayed correctly in R.
I am reading the data from an .xlsx file using package readxl and function read_excel. 

Please tell me if you need to know anything more.

Comment: `> sessionInfo()R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] readxl_0.1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.3  Rcpp_0.12.10`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're running into a bug in R's handling of native text on Windows (see, e.g. https://github.com/patperry/r-corpus/issues/5). This is fixed in the development version of R, but in the meantime you can work around the problem with `as_utf8` from the `utf8` package

```
# install.packages("utf8")
which(data$x == utf8::as_utf8("žaba"))
```